# how to sync local SQLite database with remote Database for delete operation?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I have a local sqlite database in android app running on multiple devices to sync with remote database. Everytime I fetch data to show on UI, I got data from local database, and later query from remote database and insert them into local database, using below code:

```
           database.replaceOrThrow(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
```

this runs ok except for someone delete from one device. How do I got to know which row in my local database need to be removed when the row in remote database is deleted?

there are two options which I don't like either:
1) clear the local data whenever I fetch from remote
2) compare local data with remote data to find out which row is missing in remote data, and then delete from local database.

Is there any best practice for such common situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with option number 2. You can easily calculate the delta between your local DB and the remote. For instance, you can create two ArrayList's containing the projection over the primary key or another key of your records. Then you calculate the difference between the local list and the remote list with removeAll(Collection). At this point you have a List of all the keys of records which no longer exist in your remote DB and which therefore can be erased from your local DB.

Comment: Thanks for giving the tip for that! It seems this is the best way

Comment: Of course this will not work if you are using autoincrement on primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this out:

- Store the `time`
  at which the `Modification` is Done is your `Remote` Db.
- In `Shared Preference` Store the Time of your table `creation` and `updation`.Also `update` accordingly.
- Finally compare :  `remote_table_time > table_time` and fetch those entry whose time is `greater than` your table `creation` time

Comment: by this way I can only get to know if my local data is out of date, but cannot help me deleting my local record. What is more, I am using rest API to add/remove row and hardly to get such information, I guess.

Comment: Time stamps will not work, particularly if you have high transaction volumes. Guaranteeing the synchronisation of the remote database server clock and the mobile device is also not possible, especially across different time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Applying any hand rolled syncing logic will be complex, difficult to debug and a nightmare to maintain. Your issue seems to assume that the remote DB is the source of truth but if you are allowing users to make data changes while "offline" then you need to retrospectively sync local changes to the remote store also.

I suggest you take a squiz at the [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).